# Eclipse Scout Neon Delete empty row dot trigger save

Tags: save, delete-row, eclipse-scout

In one form I have system OK button :

```
@Order(910.0)
public class SaveButton extends AbstractOkButton {

  @Override
  protected String getConfiguredLabel() {

    return TEXTS.get("Save");
  }
}
```

and I have tableField ...

If I add new empty row in this table `execStore` is called when pressing save button, but if I delete this empty row and press save button nothing is called, button only close form.

How to solve this? I would like to be able to delete empty row.

### EDIT :

I figure it out that all rows where only smart fields are filled in, on delete it doesn't detect change. (not only empty rows...)

Problem is that `checkSaveNeeded` of the form return that nothing was changed in `doOk` method.

Answer (score 0):

How do you add your row?

You can mark the row as inserted or not. See: `addRow(newRow, markAsInserted);` on the Table.

---

You second question is "How does a Table Field computes if the form needs to be stored or not"?

You can implement you custom logic on with `execIsSaveNeeded()`. See this question on the Scout forum:
https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&th=477037&goto=1042295#msg_1042295

---

Your last point is: when a row has the status `ITableHolder.STATUS_NON_CHANGED` in an editable table. When the value in a `SmartColumn` is changed with a `SmartField`, the status of the row is not changed to `ITableHolder.STATUS_UPDATED`.

I just tested it and it works as expected.

---

For row deletion, it depends on how your table field is configured. What is the value of the property `isAutoDiscardOnDelete()`.

The doc here is still valid with Neon: [Table > Delete a row from the table](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Scout/Concepts/Table#Delete_a_row_from_the_table)

With `isAutoDiscardOnDelete()` returning `true` (this is the case if `getConfiguredAutoDiscardOnDelete()` returns `true`), when you remove a row in your table field, it is discarded. There is nothing to save because there is no deleted row in the table field (Everything is explained in the wiki section I have mentioned)

If you want to persit a deletion on the server, you should not use discard the row but just delete it. This way you get the information in the FormData and from there you can work with the row status as described here: [TableData](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Scout/Concepts/TableData) (again old doc from our wiki, because it works like this since years. This it not new with Neon).

Comment: How I insert row I think it doesn't matter, because I add cell click save, edit same form again, delete row, save, but this save doesn't call execStore. I know I could override execIsSaveNeeded(), but shouldn't table handel deletion of the row by it self? My hack is that when I delete row I call touch();, but I don't like this.

Comment: As far I could test it with M6, everything works as expected. I have udpated my post.

Comment: I have getConfiguredAutoDiscardOnDelete set to true. But we currently use M5

Comment: The table code is old nothing new with M6... (as you can see from the old documentation in the wiki)